# I added this to my .bash_profile but I neglected to label it and forgot what it means exactly

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I remember broadly what it does, but not specifically:

```
    if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
    fi
```

What is the exact purpose for it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sources a `~/.bashrc` file if it exists and loads the contents of that file.

The short answer to your question is: you did this so no matter how you get to your machine, via a shell opened in an interactive desktop session or an ssh login to the machine, your `bash` shell has a consistent setup to it.

The longer answer for why you had to do it this way lies below...

The reason you'd want to do this is steeped in bash history: one of those files is used for interactive logins, the other is used for non-interactive logins. The thought behind having two different setups is you might want some things in your interactive shell (a fancy prompt, a message of the day, colourization of your command output, etc.) that you wouldn't want in a non-interactive session because it trips up programmatic access to input and output and what not.

For most users though you want both environments to be the same. Most of us aren't running complicated enough bash setups to warrant separating out interactive and non-interactive setups like this.

The `.bash_profile` is executed for login shells, while `.bashrc` is executed for interactive non-login shells.

There's [a nice article by Josh Staiger that talks about why one over the other and how to remember where to put things](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html). Allow me to quote some of it here:

> **What is a login or non-login shell?**
>
> When you login (type username and password) via console, either sitting at the machine, or remotely via `ssh`: `.bash_profile` is executed to configure your shell before the initial command prompt.
>   But, if you’ve already logged into your machine and open a new terminal window (`xterm`) inside Gnome or KDE, then `.bashrc` is executed before the window command prompt. `.bashrc` is also run when you start a new bash instance by typing `/bin/bash` in a terminal.
>
> **Mac OS X — an exception**
>
> An exception to the terminal window guidelines is Mac OS X’s `Terminal.app`, which runs a login shell by default for each new terminal window, calling `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc`. Other GUI terminal emulators may do the same, but most tend not to.
>
> **Recommendation**
>
> Most of the time you don’t want to maintain two separate config files for login and non-login shells — when you set a PATH, you want it to apply to both. You can fix this by sourcing `.bashrc` from your `.bash_profile` file, then putting PATH and common settings in `.bashrc`.
>
> To do this, add the following lines to .bash_profile:
>
> ```
> if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
>     source ~/.bashrc
> fi
> ```
>
> Now when you login to your machine from a console `.bashrc` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

See Ian C's description of what the source line does

This is surrounded by an if statement

```
if x; then
  ....
fi
```

this checks on x and then runs the code between the then and the fi (The idea of fi ending and if and other endins by reverseing the beggining keyword is use in sh and related shells.

The check that is made here is `[ -f ~/.bashrc ]` which is the same as `test -f .bashrc` the if tells test to return true iff what follows -f is a file and it exists.

So the code over says if there is a .bashrc run it into your cirrent shell.